# Instantiate view controller many ties inside the same tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift

I have slide menu based on tableView. Also I have tab bar created on IB. 
First item on tab bar is like Home page. By defaut when run app that item display home screen. When select one of items from menu it should open on the same view as Home page.

//part of the code from menu item responsible to select Home page tab bar item

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
ContainerVC.tabBarViewController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

//viewWillAppear function on separated view controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
   super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DynNews")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

}

This works only once, when start app. Later on app showing up just Home page. This is because tab bar load view only once and then selecting tab index does not call viewWillAppear but I do not know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality by number of different approaches.
To navigate inside a tabbar you should embed your controllers in a navigation controller.
This image will help you understand.[image]

Further more you can take help from this [link](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) and this [link](https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/). Also you can check out number of libraries on cocoacontrols and github for the require functionality. For better understanding I would recommend [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/).

Comment: I do not have problem with menu, it is already implemented. The problem is view controller with storyboard ID called "DynNews". I manage to show that controller but only once when start app, later on I did not managed because  selecting tab bar index not trigger viewWillAppear function.

Comment: it will trigger view appear if you switch between tabs.